# How to get push notification values in phonegap using FCM?

Tags: cordova, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

I am working in PhoneGap. I want to get the push notification value that I'm getting from FCM. Now, I am getting  the notification, but I am not able to receive notification values inside my app.

PHP side FCM Code:

```
    <?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' );
$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'body'  => $_GET['body'],
    'title'     => $_GET['title'],
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
);
var_dump($msg);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'notification'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

This is my script to receive the notification

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function onLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", Fire, false);
                       }

    function Fire() {



        FCMPlugin.getToken(
          function (token) {

               var name = document.getElementById("fireup");
                 name.value = token;
                 localStorage.setItem("key",token);
          },
          function (err) {
                   alert("Error: " + 'error retrieving token: ' + err);
          }
        );

        FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
                if(data.wasTapped){
                    alert( JSON.stringify(data.title ) );
                }else{
                  alert( JSON.stringify(data.title ) );
                }
              },
              function(msg){
                  alert('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
              },
              function(err){
                  alert('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
              }
            );

    };


</script>
```

Comment: When i tab on notification i want to get title and body inside app, but i am getting undefined.

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: I also want to say that when i am using this tester https://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com/ , i am getting notification as well as values of notification when tapping

Comment: this is how i am passing values <yourdomainname>/sendnotification.php?id=<your_firebase_id>&title=<title>&body=<body>

Comment: This is i am getting {"multicast_id":5557799655301185254,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1481702163032202%96ef985796ef9857"}]}

Comment: i am getting notification i just want that when i tap on notification i should get that values inside my app

Comment: i have used var_dump($msg) and i got array(4) { ["body"]=> string(19) "How are you?" ["title"]=> string(4) "Hey!" ["vibrate"]=> int(1) ["sound"]=> int(1) } {"multicast_id":8176666129894703254,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1481704051491657%96ef985796ef9857"}]}

Comment: You There???????????????????

Comment: I got it sir, I was not getting the data , i was only getting notifications value so I decided to put static and it finally worked

Comment: Yes you are right , i think the problem is "data" which is not coming when notification comes, When i tap on notification the app (Plugin) look for "data" feild which is undefined

Comment: Sir I also Got the solution for this Please check my answer

Comment: i think you won't get whats in payload if notification type is `notification` try `data` instead :)

Comment: and the HTML? Who is fireup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what helped me

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyCpN9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' );
$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'body'  => $_GET['body'],
    'title'     => $_GET['title'],
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'                  => $msg,
        'notification'      => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close($ch);
//echo $result;
echo json_encode(array("data"=>$msg));
?>
```